# Spring Boot test fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-test

When running the following test in a multi-module Maven Spring Boot `2.1.3.RELEASE` project:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    UService uService;

    @Test
    public void getMunicipalZips() throws Exception {
        Set<MunicipalityDto> res = uService.getMunicipalZips("FR");
...
}
...
```

it fails with:

```
2023-09-11 13:25:51.589 ERROR 54426 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration$AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@ed17bee]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
...
```

The test SpringBootApp is declared as follows in the `src/test/com.root.package`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the project `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bla.bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <name>my-service</name>
    <description>Service layer for XXX</description>
    <version>4.6.32-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-statemachine.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-statemachine.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bla.bla</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-domain</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bla.bla</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-soap</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-statemachine-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-statemachine.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Remove the spring security dependencies and use `spring-boot-starter-security` instead. Remove `spring-web` dependency and `spring-context-support`. Replace the freemarker one with `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` instead. Due to your excessive dependency management you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring (Boot) which isn't going to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yep, thank you so much. It's an old legacy project I inherited, so I have to refactor a lot. Removing/replacing the dependencies fixed the previous error (Yay!). Now I'm struggling to fix other ones saying `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available`

Comment: Which is a different issue. Did you configure the `spring.mail` properties?

Comment: @M.Denim, Fixed, the email-related properties were not defined in the corresponding maven module. Thanks again for your help :).